# How to convert a string datatype column to date format in hive

Tags: string, date, hadoop, hive, bigdata

Could you please guide with below query.
I need to convert below string column to date.

Input and expected output is provided in screenshot.

[image: 1]

Input table: column maturity_date is in string datatype.
I tried below but not working as expected
`to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(maturity_date,'MM/DD/YYYY H:mm:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lower case letters. Upper case means another thing (day of year (D) and week-year (Y)).

```
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(maturity_date,'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct input format is `'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss'`, not `'MM/DD/YYYY H:mm:ss'`

Correct output format is `yyyy-MM-dd`, not `yyyy-mm-dd.` mm is minutes. `MM` is month

Read more about date format used in Hive here [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)